# Why is simple C++ OpenMP parallel for loop slower?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a relatively simple for loop that I would like to parallelize with OpenMP. For some reason, the parallel version is slower than the serial version. Here is the function and loop in question:

```cpp
template<typename T, class UnaryOperation>
void State:apply_diagmatrix(const std::vector<T>& matrix, const UnaryOperation& transformation)
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (uint64_t i=0; i<dim_; ++i) {
        state_[i] *= transformation(matrix[i]);
    }
}
```

where `state_` is `std::vector<std::complex<double>>`. This function is called by another function where the `UnaryOperation transformation` is defined as

```cpp
auto exp_func = [dt](double matrix_term) {
    return std::complex<double>{std::cos(dt*matrix_term), -std::sin(dt*matrix_term)};
};
```

However, running the program with this parallel section is actually slower than running the serial version (without the `#pragma omp` directive). This is the case even when `dim_ > 4096`, where I would expect the overhead to be much smaller compared to the benefit of parallelizing 4096 executions of `exp_func`.

Of course, the entire program does much more than just this loop. Nevertheless, from profiling my code I know that the `apply_diagmatrix` function has significant relative cost. Hence, I would expect measurable benefit after parallelizing it.

I also tried to benchmark the parallel vs the serial version of just the loop in question. In that case, there is a clear benefit of the parallel version once `dim_ > 512`. Why am I seeing this benefit only when running the loop in isolation. What is the difference when the loop is part of a larger code? Any ideas?

**Edit**: From the comments it seems clear that the problem is not obvious without some more context. I will go back and look whether I can extract some min. reproducible example without the need to share the entire code.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you apply. You wouldn't have applied the "c" tag if you had.

Comment: Instead of threads, why not SIMD?

Comment: Not sure what `transformation` is, but assuming it's a no-op, it sure looks like each iteration is going to compete for access to memory.  An arithmetic operation like _multiply_ (the `*=` in your example) happens at light-speed compared to a memory access.  If the `_state[i]` were a thread-local temp (stack variable) it would be semantically more clear that the `transformation` function does not read from `_state` (the famous aliasing problem of C++).

Comment: Is OpenMP threading used anywhere else in your program? Or is it used exclusively for the shown loop?

Comment: 4096 cosine/sine calculations is nowhere near enough to kill the overhead caused by OMP in general. Each iteration in that for loop must do some substantial work for there to be any benefit, If you make the for loop nested so that each thread does 100k trigonometric operations you may see some gain.

Comment: 1. Have you set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable, to name something obvious? 2. Try a much larger number of points. 3. Since the loop in isolation speeds up, clearly we need the context which you are not giving us.

Comment: @SvenNilsson I guess I would agree with you, except that I tried writing a benchmark just for the loop and then the benefit was clear already at 512 calculations. That is where my confusion comes from: if the overhead is so significant, why does the parallelization work in that case?

Comment: A [mre] would probably help us to help you.

Comment: Random comment: if you know about templating and lambdas, why aren't you using range-based for loops? OpenMP handles those just fine.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout yep, I tried varying the OMP_NUM_THREADS. When only the for loop is executed, the impact is clear, for `dim_ > 512` the speed up is proportional to `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. When the entire program is executed, there is a similar slow down irrespective of num threads.

Comment: You need to dig deeper.... start by putting a printf("%llu %d\n", i, GetCurrentThreadId()); inside the loop to make sure that it actually gets executed in parallel the way you would expect. And then compare this output to your isolated benchmark case.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout re. random comment: well, I am iterating over two vectors here. Not sure how I could use range for loop...

Comment: You can not parallelize every algorithm. If your bottleneck is your memory access, why do you expect 1 thread is slower than 1024 parallel threads if your memory is single or dual channel?

Comment: you iterate over two vectors? I only see one vector in your code.

Comment: "is actually slower" How are you measuring this?

Comment: @SvenNilsson `state_` and `matrix`

Comment: You're right. We still have to wait a year for the zip operator. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view

Comment: @n.m. I've ran google benchmark on it. You can also see the slow down with simple `time` command

Comment: @VictorEijkhout yeah, who knew good ol' python will lead the way...

Comment: Oh, when it comes to array notation C++ is 35 years behind Fortran....

Comment: FYI: There is an [overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/exp) for `std::exp` which takes a complex number. Apart form nicer looking code this is potentially faster as there might be terms that are calculated both for sinus and cosinus.